# Exception only on Android 3.0

Tags: android, serialization, android-3.0-honeycomb, kryo

I am using Kryonet for an Android app, and works perfectly on all Android versions but the 3.0 version. I am getting the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16861): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-30
E/AndroidRuntime(16861): com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: start=0 end=5 data.length=512 index=6 length=5
E/AndroidRuntime(16861): Serialization trace:
E/AndroidRuntime(16861): email (com.momasoft.sudokutournament.network.Network$Login)
E/AndroidRuntime(16861): at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:203)
```

Why does this happen only on Android 3.0? Is there a way to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the string? How does it get set to a 5 character string

Comment: It is an email as String input by the user. The problem is, it works perfectly on any other version of android!

Comment: Have you done any validation on the email address?

Comment: Yes, and I am sure it has nothing to do with the string itself... There must be somethin in the seralization methods that Android 3.0 doesn't like :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, debugging the Kryo library:
I suggest to change the following code from kryo:

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.java:307

```
/***Change this: ***/
value.getBytes(0, charCount, buffer, position);
position += charCount;

/***for this: ***/
byte[] valueB = value.getBytes();
for (int j = 0; j < valueB.length; j++) {
   this.writeByte(valueB[j]);
}
```

the getBytes(int start, int end, byte[] elem, int offset) is deprecated, and gives problems in android 3.0.